# Grey Box on Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Seems like there was an update to the Google Maps API that if a pixel value for width & height are not set, then it just renders a grey box. Problem I am having is I need a full-width map.

The map does render, if you drag the map to the right, you can see the map.

I tried adding this to an event `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` It did not help.

Here is my Markup

```
<div class="map-holder">
      <div id="google-map"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my js

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXX, XX.XXXXX),
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        draggable: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        zoomControl: false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXX, XX.XXXXX),
        map: map,
        title: 'Some place',
        visible: true,
        place: 'Some place'
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(center);
});
```

Comment: What does your CSS look like?  How are you including the API? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and here is why I had the grey box and no map. I have 2 tabs - one is visible and one is hidden - one map is within the visible another one is within the hidden - I have absolutely the same minimum code to initialize the maps other than the div ids.

I put the hidden map div within the visible area and run - and it worked and rendered just like the visible one.

The moral of my story is - if it is located within the hidden div - it will not initialize properly - possibly due to the DOM not making certain things accessible due to the `display:none;`

I just hope it helps - this is not the first time I ran into this so I figured I would let my code brothers know the deal!

Answer (score 4):

Okay seems like I found a fix, just add a 3.20 version number.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.20"></script>
```

Comment: Wondering if someone can provide some insight on why this fixes it?

Comment: Can  you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: This fixed the issue for me also. I'd have thought omitting the version would have given the latest?

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if you forget a mapTypeId which is a required attribute.  It can also happen if you forget to pass in map options.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting height and width of your container **directly in the html markup** instead of a stylesheet or `<style>` tag ie. in your case:

`<div id="google-map" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>`

happy mapping!